# Validate user input against ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am having issues with the following part of my code.
when "nn" is entered  i get invalid code.
when valid code is entered i get invalid code however this only happens once.
program doesn't seem to work as intended. Please assist.

```
    System.out.println("ENTER CODE (nn to Stop) : ");
    ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
    .
    .
    .
    .


    ArrayList<Code> codeList = new ArrayList<Code>();


    for (Product product : list) {
        System.out.print("CODE : ");
        String pcode = scan.next();
        if (pcode.equalsIgnoreCase("nn")) {
            break;
        }

        if (!(code.equalsIgnoreCase(product.getCode()))) {
            System.out.println("Invalid code, please enter valid code.");
            System.out.print("CODE : ");
            pcode = scan.next();

        }

        System.out.print("QUANTITY : ");
        int quan = scan.nextInt();
        while (quan > 20) {
            System.out.println("Purchase of more than 20 items are not allowed, please enter lower amount.");
            System.out.print("QUANTITY : ");
            quan = scan.nextInt();
        }
        codeList.add(new Code(pcode, quan));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `continue` instead of `break`.

Also, you should only call `code = scan.next()` once inside the loop; otherwise you'll skip over some items.

```
String code = scan.next();
boolean match = false;
for (Product product : list) {
    if (code.equalsIgnoreCase(product.getCode())) {
        match = true;
        break;
    }
}
// now only if match is false do you have an invalid product code.
```

**Update:**

> I still can't get this to work. What I am trying to do is test user
>   input to make sure that product code exists, if not prompt that the
>   product code entered is invalid and asks for correct code. I also need
>   to have the condition to stop order when "nn" is entered. I have tried
>   while loops, do-while loops etc. i can't seem to get it right. Please
>   assist. My problem is with writing code for multiple conditions. When
>   one is working correctly the other isn't.

```
while (true) {
    final String code = scan.next();
    if (isExitCode(code)) {
        break;
    }
    if (!isValidCode(code)) {
        System.out.println("Invalid code, please enter valid code.");
        continue;
    }
    int quantity = -1;
    while (true) {
        quantity = scan.nextInt();
        if (!isValidQuantity(quantity)) {
            System.out.println("bad quantity");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    // if you've got here, you have a valid code and a valid 
    // quantity; deal with it as you see fit.
}
```

Now you just need to write the methods isExitCode(), isValidCode(), and isValidQuantity().

Comment: i did try 'continue' however i need to break from loop entirely when "nn" is entered. I removed the 'code = scan.next() from within if block however same results.

Comment: So when you're looping through products, the current product you're on is the only one that will be accepted; you're comparing the entered code to the code of the current product and treating it as invalid otherwise.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am trying to prevent user from entering an invalid product code. I want to accept only codes available in ArrayList created here    'ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();'  I think    'for (Product product : list)' is the wrong way of doing this. Will contains() work on multidimensional ArrayLists? What is the best way to compare user input against ArrayList in my case?

Comment: Then you want to loop over all products for any entry, and only reject it if none of them matches.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: without for loop i get error in calling getCode() method. I tried list.getCode and Product.getCode and i'm getting undefined method and Cannot make a static reference to a non-static method which makes sense.

Comment: thanks again, im gonna play around with your suggestion. The "nn" code and user prompt "invalid code" has to be incorporated into the program.

Comment: I still can't get this to work. What i am trying to do is test user input to make sure that product code exists, if not prompt that the product code entered is invalid and asks for correct code. I also need to have the condition to stop order when "nn" is entered. I have tried while loops, do-while loops etc. i can't seem to get it right. Please assist. My problem is with writing code for multiple conditions. When one is working correctly the other isn't.